# HTML form is getting hanged/Freezes when i try to do any action on screen in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, angular7

Hi my angular form is getting hanged when am try to scroll up and down and try to select drop down options, selecting items in list control. My form contains input controls which has regex patterns,  controls. All these controls are in my child html form.
And if i clear cache its working fine.

Please suggest me to fix this issue.

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question - atleast mention the reason why it was downvoted and provide the oppurtunity to the questioner to modify it. Simply downvoting without comments is not going to help a new comer. You need to understand that it was easier for people who joined earlier to get up votes for their questions and answers. Now it is very difficult because many who joined earlier had already asked basic questions or answered those basic questions and they are still earning votes from those. For a new comer it is really difficult to get votes. Have some consideration for that.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method function from direct html can be costlier Operation which might have called your application function multiple times apart of life cycle hooks.

It's better to use always variable instead of functions if you are not using it already. Please share your code snippet or stackblitz url for better help from community